# Randomly sorting an array

Tags: language-agnostic, sorting, random

Does there exist an algorithm which, given an ordered list of symbols {a1, a2, a3, ..., ak}, produces in O(n) time a new list of the same symbols in a random order without bias? "Without bias" means the probability that any symbol *s* will end up in some position *p* in the list is 1/k.

Assume it is possible to generate a non-biased integer from 1-k inclusive in O(1) time. Also assume that O(1) element access/mutation is possible, and that it is possible to create a new list of size k in O(k) time.

In particular, I would be interested in a 'generative' algorithm. That is, I would be interested in an algorithm that has O(1) initial overhead, and then produces a new element for each slot in the list, taking O(1) time per slot.

If no solution exists to the problem as described, I would still like to know about solutions that do not meet my constraints in one or more of the following ways (and/or in other ways if necessary):

- the time complexity is worse than O(n).
- the algorithm is biased with regards to the final positions of the symbols.
- the algorithm is not generative.

I should add that this problem appears to be the same as the problem of randomly sorting the integers from 1-k, since we can sort the list of integers from 1-k and then for each integer *i* in the new list, we can produce the symbol ai.

Comment: Which shuffle algorithms have you considered so far? Have you excluded them for specific reasons?

Comment: @Greg: I hadn't really found anything useful, but I seem to have been searching with the wrong keywords (random sorting, randomized sorting...). Looking for 'randomized permutations', and 'shuffling' are returning more results. I have yet to find anything generative though.

Comment: the Knuth shuffle *is* generative, according to your definition of that term.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, it is. Thanks and +1. I blame my failure to notice that on how early it is in the morning :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - the [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation).

Comment: Perfect! It's surprisingly simple, too.

Answer (score 4):

The [Fisher-Yates Shuffle (Knuth Shuffle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is what you are looking for.